# call awk within perl script

Tags: perl, awk

I would like to input a file and call awk using elements from each row of the file, one awk command per line. Right now I'm using a perl script to create an array and the print the awk command line I want to run. However, I'm sure there is a better way to actually run the awk command within the perl script.

File looks like:

```
1 rs78641116 8374297 3374297 13374297
1 rs34269918 8424984 3424984 13424984
1 rs533123 29141155 24141155 34141155
1 rs1498232 30433951 25433951 35433951
```

Code below:

```
#! perl -w

open( my $file, "<", "sim.snps" ) or die $!;
while (<$file>) {
    my @snps=split;
    print "awk \'\$2>=$snps[3]\&\&\$2<=$snps[4]\{print\$1,\$2,\$3,\$4\}\' \..\/phasing_and_imputation\/1000GP_Phase3_chr$snps[0].legend > $snps[1]\.legend\n"
    }
```

Output awk commands:

```
awk '$2>=3374297&&$2<=13374297{print$1,$2,$3,$4}' ../phasing_and_imputation/1000GP_Phase3_chr1.legend > rs78641116.legend
awk '$2>=3424984&&$2<=13424984{print$1,$2,$3,$4}' ../phasing_and_imputation/1000GP_Phase3_chr1.legend > rs34269918.legend
awk '$2>=24141155&&$2<=34141155{print$1,$2,$3,$4}' ../phasing_and_imputation/1000GP_Phase3_chr1.legend > rs533123.legend
awk '$2>=25433951&&$2<=35433951{print$1,$2,$3,$4}' ../phasing_and_imputation/1000GP_Phase3_chr1.legend > rs1498232.legend
```

Does anyone have a solution to run awk instead of printing the awk commands?

Comment: ... you're already in Perl. Why are you calling out to awk?   Perl can do everything awk can, in about as much code..

Comment: I'm a perl novice. Not sure how to do this simply.

Comment: First convert each of the `awk` output commands to Perl, then incorporate the result into the `while` loop..

Comment: Use a2p to convert your awk program to perl.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one Perl solution to your problem as I understand it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;  # avoid a bunch of `or die` clauses

# First, load the criteria for splitting into the output files
my %files = ();

# extra block level wrapping the $ranges file access; file
# is automatically closed at the end of the block
{ 
  open my $ranges, '<', 'sim.snps';
  while (<$ranges>)  {
    (undef, my $key, undef, my ($min, $max)) = split;
    $files{$key} = { min => $min, max => $max };

    # go ahead and open the output file while we're here
    open $files{$file}{fh}, '>', "$key.legend";
  }
} # $ranges filehandle closed here

# another file-access block
{
  # open the data file
  open my $data, '<', '../phasing_and_imputation/1000GP_Phase3_chr1.legend';

  while (<$data>) {
    # split the data into fields
    my @f = split;

    # loop over the output files and write the relevant parts of this line
    # to the ones that want it
    while (my ($file, $data) = each %files) {
      if ($f[1] >= $data->{min}  && $f[1] <= $data->{max}) {
        print { $data->{fh} } join(' ', @f[0..3]), "\n";
      }
    }
  }
} # data file closed here

# close the output files
foreach my $data (values %files) {
  close $data->{fh};
}
```